# My .zip file size is 45mb but it's showing the error of large file size on AWS layer

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture, serverless-offline

I am using the serverless framework for the deployment. It's throwing the following error while we are deploying it on the AWS. But my zip file size is 45mb and unzipped size is 130mb on local.

Serverless Error ----------------------------------------

An error occurred: SharedLambdaLayer - Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 27f9378e-b9ea-42c5-ad73-a3b7cf9d584c).

This is my environment
Operating System: win32
Node Version: 12.19.0
Framework Version: 2.35.0
Plugin Version: 4.5.3
SDK Version: 4.2.2
Components Version: 3.8.2

Following is my .yml file content

```
service: rxd-layers
frameworkVersion: '2'
useDotenv: true
unresolvedVariablesNotificationMode: error
configValidationMode: error
plugins:
serverless-plugin-git-variables
serverless-dotenv-plugin

custom:
stageVariables:
gitBranch: ${opt:stage, git:branch}

package:
include:
- /nodejs/node_modules/shared # no need to add this yourself, this plugin does it for you
exclude:
- /nodejs/node_modules/**
- /nodejs/shared/**

provider:
stage: ${opt:stage, git:branch}
name: aws
runtime: nodejs12.x
region: ${env:AWS_REGION_CRED, 'us-east-1'}
versionFunctions: true
lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221


layers:
shared:
path: shared
description: This layer is for node packages of all services


resources:
Outputs:
SharedLayerExport:
Value:
Ref: SharedLambdaLayer
Export:
Name: SharedLambdaLayer
```

Comment: Hi Arslan, did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm having a similar issue with trying to add Sentry Python Lambda Layer to a Python function - all the files unzipped appear to be much smaller than 250MB but I still seem to get this error.

Comment: Destroying the stack and creating a new one fixed the issue but this is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is was due to `geo-tz` library. It was creating the unzip size almost more than `255MB` for just geo-tz on my `linux` environment on AWS, this was the main problem. So I just uninstall this package. and after that My layer deployed correctly.